# Parse multiple delimiters and embedded braces in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have inherited a project from someone who didn't think ahead to data analysis.  As a result I have output data files with multiple delimiters, including braces of multiple types and varying degrees of embedding to group data, and commas to separate numbers with braces.  There is also some plain text sentences in places for good measure.

Can anyone help with a simple way to turn the embedded structure and delineation into a data frame in **R**?

Here is a sample:

```
[(3, None, 1), (1, 0.36, 1), (3, None, 1), (2, 0.41, 1), (5, 0.47, 1), (6, 0.36, 1), (2, 0.45, 1), (2, 0.36, 1), (4, 0.39, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (1, 0.47, 1), (7, 0.44, 1), (4, 0.39, 1), (6, 0.38, 1), (9, 0.39, 1), (5, 0.37, 1), (8, 0.41, 1), (9, 0.38, 1), (1, 0.44, 1), (9, 0.38, 1), (4, 0.36, 1), (8, 0.41, 1), (7, 0.38, 1), (7, 0.41, 1), (7, 0.36, 1), (7, 0.39, 1), (9, 0.41, 1), (5, 0.36, 1), (8, 0.31, 1), (6, 0.38, 1), (1, 0.44, 1), (3, None, 1), (5, 0.59, 1), (7, 0.52, 1), (7, 0.44, 1), (7, 0.38, 1), (8, 0.34, 1), (9, 0.39, 1), (3, None, 1), (7, 0.44, 1), (7, 0.53, 1), (8, 0.36, 1), (3, 0.36, 0), (8, 0.34, 1), (5, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (5, 0.52, 1), (3, None, 1), (9, 0.55, 1), (9, 0.36, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (2, 0.73, 1), (9, 0.36, 1), (7, 0.44, 1), (4, 0.45, 1), (4, 0.62, 1), (9, 0.39, 1), (3, 0.31, 0), (1, 0.42, 1), (4, 0.34, 1), (5, 0.53, 1), (8, 0.34, 1), (3, None, 1), (8, 0.47, 1), (6, 0.39, 1), (1, 0.42, 1), (5, 0.53, 1), (1, 0.53, 1), (8, 0.62, 1), (1, 0.39, 1), (8, 0.44, 1), (8, 0.45, 1), (9, 0.38, 1), (1, 0.36, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (6, 0.36, 1), (7, 0.36, 1), (9, 0.39, 1), (8, 0.41, 1), (8, 0.31, 1), (3, None, 1), (2, 0.36, 1), (4, 0.36, 1), (2, 0.31, 1), (9, 0.36, 1), (1, 0.31, 1), (4, 0.34, 1), (1, 0.56, 1), (7, 0.61, 1), (9, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (1, 0.36, 1), (1, 0.53, 1), (5, 0.33, 1), (3, None, 1), (1, 0.39, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (9, 0.33, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (5, 0.44, 1), (2, 0.52, 1), (1, 0.42, 1), (6, 0.38, 1), (9, 0.33, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (5, 0.31, 1), (6, 0.31, 1), (8, 0.31, 1), (2, 0.33, 1), (9, 0.33, 1), (1, 0.56, 1), (6, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (7, 0.34, 1), (5, 0.34, 1), (2, 0.36, 1), (2, 0.47, 1), (3, None, 1), (2, 0.39, 1), (2, 0.36, 1), (6, 0.31, 1), (1, 0.53, 1), (5, 0.45, 1), (7, 0.42, 1), (5, 0.45, 1), (2, 0.39, 1), (2, 0.45, 1), (6, 0.36, 1), (2, 0.45, 1), (1, 0.39, 1), (1, 0.34, 1), (4, 0.39, 1), (2, 0.34, 1), (2, 0.31, 1), (3, 0.31, 0), (8, 0.39, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (6, 0.31, 1), (5, 0.38, 1), (9, 0.34, 1), (7, 0.31, 1), (1, 0.33, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (6, 0.38, 1), (5, 0.38, 1), (9, 0.38, 1), (2, 0.5, 1), (8, 0.44, 1), (8, 0.39, 1), (4, 0.38, 1), (5, 0.5, 1), (9, 0.48, 1), (2, 0.59, 1), (8, 0.41, 1), (7, 0.41, 1), (3, None, 1), (4, 0.5, 1), (4, 0.36, 1), (7, 0.38, 1), (5, 0.44, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (6, 0.41, 1), (3, None, 1), (7, 0.39, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (2, 0.34, 1), (9, 0.36, 1), (4, 0.36, 1), (5, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (6, 0.36, 1), (5, 0.33, 1), (4, 0.44, 1), (7, 0.34, 1), (8, 0.48, 1), (6, 0.34, 1), (8, 0.38, 1), (3, None, 1), (4, 0.31, 1), (3, 0.31, 0)]
 Percentage of correctly suppressed responses per five-target section: 
[80, 80, 100, 80]
 Average reaction time per five-target section: 
[0.4, 0.43, 0.39, 0.39]
 Percentage of correctly suppressed responses per ten-target section: 
[80, 90]
 Average reaction time per ten-target section: 
[0.41, 0.39]
```

Ideally the first line would be turned into a 3 column data frame, second line ignored, 3rd line a 4 integer vector, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readLines` to get your data in, and then `gsub` and `strsplit` to sort it all out:

```
#txt <- readLines(textConnection("<insert your text here>"))
#or probably more appropriately
txt <- readLines("filename.txt")  

# remove labels
txt <- txt[-c(2,4,6,8)]

# remove first [ character
txt <- lapply(txt,function(x) substr(x,2,nchar(x)-1))

# reformat element 1
txt[[1]] <- gsub("[()]","",txt[[1]])
txt[[1]] <- gsub("None","0",txt[[1]])
txt[[1]] <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(txt[[1]],",")))
txt[[1]] <- data.frame(matrix(txt[[1]],ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))

# reformat elements 2-5
txt[2:5] <- lapply(txt[2:5],function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,","))))
```

Result:

```
txt

#[[1]]
#  X1   X2 X3
#1  3 0.00  1
#2  1 0.36  1
#3  3 0.00  1
#4  2 0.41  1
#5  5 0.47  1
#6  6 0.36  1
# etc... etc...
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  80  80 100  80
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.40 0.43 0.39 0.39
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 80 90
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 0.41 0.39
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!.  Small edit for anyone in the future - if reading text from a file name, it should be:  

`txt <- readLines("filename.txt") #ie remove the textConnection()`